# View SQL query in Slick

Tags: sql, scala, slick

Is there a way to observe an SQL statement that will be generated by `Query`?
For example, I have this:
`val q = actions.filter(v => v.actionHash === hash && v.carriedAt > past)`
Can I view its underlying raw SQL?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

**Slick 2.X:**

You can print the query statement as shown on the [Slick documentation](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.1/queries.html#querying):

```
val invoker = q.invoker
val statement = q.selectStatement
```

For other type of statements look at `insertStatement`, `deleteStatement` and `updateStatement`.

**Slick 3.X:**

```
val res = table.filter(_.id === 1L).result
res.statements.foreach(println)
```

[Docs](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/queries.html#querying).

Comment: This doesn't work with `DBIOAction`, is there another way for this?

Comment: @Mhd.Tahawi could you provide an example? I don't think I get your question.

Comment: The thing is, `.statements` works fine for a `SQLAction`, but it doesn't exist for a `DBIOAction`, which is what you get when you compose a bunch of `SQLAction`s together in a for comprehension and yield the final result.  Far as I can tell, Monadic joins lose the ability to use `.statements`.  That's kind of a pain...

Comment: @JustinduCoeur right, I see that `SQLAction` is a subclass of `DBIOAction` and `BasicAction` and that the actual implementations are Invokers (like `StreamingInvokerAction`). Maybe the statement print can only be done at invoker level and not in the upper trait, unfortunately I don't have an answer for that.

Comment: @EndeNeu Agreed, although I think it's a hole in the API.  Ideally, traits like DBIOAction would provide a best-effort implementation of `.statements`, based on what they are compositing.  Not the end of the world, but it was frustrating to discover the lack, given how useful `.statements` is for debugging...

Comment: `DBIOAction` can't implement `.statements` since `DBIOAction` doesn't even have to contain a SQL statement. It could be just about anything in there.

Answer (score 31):

For slick 3.0

```
println(sortedQuery.result.statements.headOption)
```

Comment: Works as well on Slick version 3.1.1