# Scala: Is there anyway to see the underlying SQL query for a DBIOAction in slick

Tags: scala, slick

The title says it all.

I need to see the underlying query of a `DBIOAction`
**EDIT 1**
When trying the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23434286/view-sql-query-in-slick) it fails with the following:

> Error:(978, 19) value result is not a member of
>   slick.dbio.DBIOAction[Unit,slick.dbio.NoStream,slick.dbio.Effect.Write]
>       logger.info(myAction.result.statements.headOption)

which is normal since the [docs](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.0/api/index.html#slick.dbio.DBIOAction) do not mention `result` to be part of the `trait`.
I am using slick 3.2.0-M1

**EDIT 2**
`result` doesn't seem to be an implicit.
In the same scope, I can use it on `Query` object but not on a `DBIOAction` object. 
unless `DBIOAction` has another implicit with the same name that should be imported separately, but there is nothing in the docs about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [View SQL query in Slick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23434286/view-sql-query-in-slick)

Comment: @chunjef Not really a duplicate, those are `DBIOActoin` and not `Queries`. it is a different `trait`

Comment: The `result` function is probably added via implicits. Try importing `api._` from your corresponding Slick profile (e.g. postgresql, can't remember the whole path) and it should compile.

Comment: @JakubKozłowski , Thanks. Would you check my `Edit 2` please :)

Comment: Ah, sorry. I mixed things up, `result` is a method added to `Query`, not `DBIOAction` (at least I've never seen it there).

Comment: Did you try just calling `.statements` on your DBIOAction?

Comment: @JakubKozłowski, didn't work either

Comment: ok, seems like it's defined on `SqlAction` - which makes sense, as not every `DBIOAction` touches SQL.

Comment: For example:
```scala
val x: FixedSqlAction[Int, NoStream, Effect.Write] = TableQuery[YourType].update(null)
x.statements
```
this compiles and should result in the queries being executed. So I'd suggest you make sure your action comes from SQL statements and don't hide that information by upcasting to DBIOAction.